# .BAT - IF command do not work

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Ok, so probably I am doing something ultra wrong.

I want to make this:

```
in C:\programs\app\install.exe
```

is installation of a program.

It should install to:

```
c:\program files\app
```

And my question is how to make IF command inside .bat file to:

```
if c:\program files\app\appStart.exe  exist start c:\program files\app\appStart.exe
if c:\program files\app\appStart.exe  not exist start C:\programs\app\install.exe
```

to make it more simple I test it on this files in this folder (never tried with folders and files from above)

```
c:\folder\1.txt
c:\folder\2.txt
c:\folder\A.txt
c:\folder\B.txt
```

And I want to make:

```
if c:\folder\1.txt exist start c:\folder\A.txt
if c:\folder\1.txt not exist start c:\folder\B.txt
```

I found tons of sites on google with answers but nothing seems to work to me they won't even open.

Was trying this:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Nowy folder" (
    REM 1.txt
    IF EXIST "1.txt" (Start "C:\folder\1.txt") ELSE (Start "C:\folder\A.txt")
) ELSE (
    REM 2.txt
    IF EXIST "2.txt" (Start "C:\folder\2.txt") ELSE (Start "C:\folder\B.txt")
)
Pause&Exit

or this 

if exist "%CD%\1.txt" (Start /wait "%CD%\A.txt") ELSE  Start /wait "%CD%\B.txt"
Pause
```

Also doesn't work.

It is no matter if I give full path or %CD% it just doesn't work.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if exist "c:\program files\app\appStart.exe" ( start "" "c:\program files\app\appStart.exe"
 ) else (start "" "C:\programs\app\install.exe")
```

You need to `"quote names containing spaces"` and the first quoted parameter to `START` becomes the window-title, so you'd put an empty-quoted string for the first parameter (or `"whatever window title you want"`)

I'm confused about the remainder of your question. Have you a further question?

Answer (score 0):

This checks for both the exe files and will use the first one in preference to the second exe.

```
@echo off
if exist "c:\program files\app\appStart.exe" (
        start "" "c:\program files\app\appStart.exe"
   ) else (
       if exist "C:\programs\app\install.exe" start "" "C:\programs\app\install.exe"
)
```

Comment: im sorry that 2.txt should not be there

it should only check if 1.txt exist and lauch A.txt or if it does not launche B.txt

but ur code will be useful for me in the future thanks :)